# Deep Rust matching: is there a better way?

Tags: rust, idioms

I just found myself writing this:

```rust
fn init_timestamps(dir: &PathBuf, file_timestamps: &'static HashMap<PathBuf,Duration>) {

    match fs::read_dir(dir) {
        Ok(iter) => iter.for_each(|result| match result {
            Ok(entry)  => {
                if entry.file_type().map(|t| t.is_dir()).unwrap_or(false) {
                    init_timestamps(&entry.path(), file_timestamps);
                } else {
                    match entry.metadata() {
                        Ok(md) => match md.modified() {
                            Ok(modified) => {
                                locked_timestamps.insert(entry.path(), modified.duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap());
                            },
                            Err(_) => ()
                        },
                        Err(_) => ()
                    };
                }
            },
            Err(_) => ()
        }),
        Err(_) => ()
    };
}
```

And I have to ask: is there a better pattern I'm missing? I tried using `.map()` at each level, which looked slightly better but gave me compiler warnings about unused Results. What I'm wanting to do, in this general case, is "if this chain of Results (or Options) exists all the way down, do X. otherwise, do nothing." I've also run into similar situations where I want to coerce "failed" points in the chain to `false` (there's a boolean check at the fullest depth).

This actually could be seen as Rust's version of the null-check problem addressed with the null-coalescing operator in other languages [such as Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`?` operator](https://m4rw3r.github.io/rust-questionmark-operator), designed for this exact task.

```
foo()?
```

is equivalent to

```
match foo() {
    Ok(t)  => t
    Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
}
```

So you can just throw `?` at the end of anything that returns a `Try` implementation. You'll have to make your function return `Result<(), E>`, but that's just as well because then your function will report its errors rather than failing silently.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I hadn't come across that until now.

Still trying to figure out how to use it while making the compiler happy, but in theory it seems like exactly what I was looking for.